# how to remove a smaller list of element lists from a larger list of element lists

Tags: python, list, subset

I have found other answers but I don't think they're doing exactly what I want. I also can't understand the answers provided so I don't know how to implement them. Since they'ree all old answers by other people, I don't think they'd answer my questions. I've tried before and no one answered.

Long story short, I messed up earlier and should have created a combo list, to begin with but I didn't. And I'm not going to rerun my other code because there is no point. Of course, it should go without saying, this obviously is not my real dataset and this only a smaller picture of what I'm trying to do.

I have two smaller lists and I created a larger combo list. Because of how the loop work, I'll have duplicates between the combo list and the smaller lists. I want to remove duplicates from the larger list.

edit: my veggie list only has veggies. my fruit list only has fruit. my combo list has both. My outputs are combinations of elements put into my input lists. In my combo list, all I want are combinations of both fruits and vegetables. I don't want combinations of only fruits and I don't want combinations of only vegetables in my combo list.

Using the example below: I don't want anything from my fruit_output and my veggie_output in my combo_output.

```
fruit_input = ["Apple", "Banana" "Pear", "Peach", "Grape"]

fruit_output = sum([list(map(list, combinations(fruit_input, i))) for i in range(len(fruit_input) + 1)], [])

veggies_input = ["Lettuce", "Cabbage", "Califlour", "Broccoli", "String_Beans", "Celery"]

veggies_output = sum([list(map(list, combinations(veggies_input, i))) for i in range(len(veggies_input) + 1)], [])

combo_input = ["Apple", "Banana" "Pear", "Peach", "Grape",
               "Lettuce", "Cabbage", "Califlour", "Broccoli", "String_Beans", "Celery"]

combo_output = sum([list(map(list, combinations(combo_input, i))) for i in range(len(combo_input) + 1)], [])
```

basically if ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear"] is in fruit_output, it should not be in combo output. All I want are combos are veggies and fruits together.

edit:
in veggie_out put you'll see stuff like this:

```
['Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Califlour'],
 ['Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Broccoli'],
 ['Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'String_Beans'],
```

in fruit_out put you'll see stuff like this:

```
['Apple', 'BananaPear', 'Grape'],
 ['Apple', 'Peach', 'Grape'],
 ['BananaPear', 'Peach', 'Grape'],
 ['Apple', 'BananaPear', 'Peach', 'Grape']]
```

in the combo you'll see all of it:

```
['Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Califlour'],
 ['Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Broccoli'],
 ['Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'String_Beans'],
['Apple', 'BananaPear', 'Grape'],
 ['Apple', 'Peach', 'Grape'],
 ['BananaPear', 'Peach', 'Grape'],
 ['Apple', 'BananaPear', 'Peach', 'Grape'],
['Apple', 'Peach', 'Grape', 'Cabbage', 'Califlour', 'Broccoli', 'Celery'],
 ['Apple', 'Peach', 'Grape', 'Cabbage', 'Califlour', 'String_Beans', 'Celery'],
 ['Apple', 'Peach', 'Grape', 'Cabbage', 'Broccoli', 'String_Beans', 'Celery'],
```

and here is what I want to happen:

```
['Apple', 'Peach', 'Grape', 'Cabbage', 'Califlour', 'Broccoli', 'Celery'],
 ['Apple', 'Peach', 'Grape', 'Cabbage', 'Califlour', 'String_Beans', 'Celery'],
 ['Apple', 'Peach', 'Grape', 'Cabbage', 'Broccoli', 'String_Beans', 'Celery'],
```

Combo is repeating what is done individually in the fruit and veggie outputs and I don't their outputs in there. I only want combinations of fruits and veggitiables. Th

Comment: Are you trying to take two lists and merge the results together with only one of each element type in the combo list? Could you provide an example output of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Brett Lepierre--I've addded what I wanted to see.

basically `fruit_output` only gives me combinations of fruits. `veggie_output` only gives me combinations of vegetables. The combo will give me combinations of only fruit, combinations of only veggies and combinations fruits and veggies. I want to remove all the combinations of only fruits and remove all the combinations of only veggies so I'm left with combinations of both fruits and veggies.

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = ("blue", "red", "green"), ("silver", "purple", "green"), ("silver", "purple", "green")
numbers = ("one", "two", "three"), ("one", "two", "three"), ("one", "two", "three")
# unique set, same set, unique set, same set
combo = ("blue", "red", "yellow"), ("silver", "purple", "green"), ("one", "two", "ten"), ("one", "two", "three")
# so we expect to see 5 unique total sets
color_numbers = colors + numbers #here we are adding the sets together

unique = set(color_numbers).union(combo) #using set to get only unique values and union to retreive the same values between lists
print(unique)
```

Output

```
{('one', 'two', 'three'), ('silver', 'purple', 'green'), ('blue', 'red', 'yellow'), ('blue', 'red', 'green'), ('one', 'two', 'ten')}
```

I believe you want sets with some kind of filter method as seen here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/union

Comment: Our outputs are different because my outputs give me lists where the elements in each input list are combined to give me unique combinations. Your solution doesn't work because the outputs I get are lists of lists. Not lists of single elements. I'm getting "unhashable as an error".

Comment: I edited my code. I would suggest performing the list manipulations then converting the lists into sets and using the set functionality and set support methods to get what you are looking for.